# how to configure nginx for different paths

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I would like to configure nginx for different locations on / and I have the following config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bla.com;
    location = / {   // on exact route match such as 'bla.com'
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/folder; // it has index.html
    }
    location / { // rest all url such as bla.com/* are captured here eg. bla.com/temp/12 
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/dist; // different folder
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

I also tried the below config with no luck -

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bla.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location = / {
        try_files $uri /folder/index.html; // it has index.html
    }
    location / { // rest all url such as bla.com/* are captured here eg. bla.com/temp/12
        try_files $uri /dist/index.html; // different folder
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with 'different locations on /'. Do you mean that you have two different websites on the root of your domain? Because I don't think that's possible (at least with the NGINX config files it isn't).

Comment: I mean if I give bla.com I want to be going to a location and bla.com/temp to some other location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating something like this:

```
server {

    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name test.example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/website1/public_html;
    }

    location /temp {
        root /var/www/website2/public_html;
    }
}
```

You can also do this with individual files like this:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/website/public_html/robots.txt;
}
```

Comment: temp is a variable here ... I am sorry I should have explained better. temp can be any path basically. I hope I make sense now

Comment: Ok, then this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/656628/nginx-catch-all-other-locations-than-given might help you.

Comment: even there the answer mentioned -  '  I think it may be to use location = /. The explicit / request will be matched by it and everything else will go to location / unless something else matches '  doesn't work which is what I am trying to figure out